# how to only show specific element when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of tabs that will each contain there own set of questions with each question having a specific answer.

The tab structure is sound and exactly how I wanted it to be when built. My problem lies with the questions and answers themselves.

The desired functionality is when a question is clicked the answer for that question should be shown. I have a simple grasp of it here with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/562sqryf/3/) but I am struggling on how to differentiate between what question is being clicked and therefore which answer to show.

Basic understanding of whats needed:

```
$('.question-text').click(function(){
   $(".answer-text").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

I saw this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZz9x/) that uses jquery's `closest` but cant figure out how to convert that to my particular code. Here is what I have tried with no avail:

```
$(".question").each(function(){
    $('.question-text').click(function(){
         var $par=$(this).closest('.answer')
         $par.find(".answer-text").slideDown("1000");
     });
})
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Your code](https://jsfiddle.net/b2hknrrj/) seems to be working. When you change the text, u see it changes according to the question. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: `$(this).closest('.question').find(".answer-text").toggleClass("hidden");`  or any other transversal method to match the relevant `.answer-text`

Comment: @AhsN It also opens every answer on the other tabs, I need it to open only **one** answer for the questions. Each tab can also have multiple questions which have their own answers. Sorry for not clarifying this more.

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm sorry but i'm not quite understanding what you're trying to tell me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove iterating question.each and simply bind click on all the question-text.

When the question-text is clicked , grab the next sibling which is your answer.

```
$('.question-text').click(function(){
         var $par=$(this).next()
         $par.find(".answer-text").toggleClass("hidden");
     });
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using parent() in your jquery, i think it is similar as FAQ question and answers view. try the below code by replacing your class names.

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.faq_question').click(function() {

    if ($(this).parent().is('.open')){
        $(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq_answer_container').animate({'height':'0'},500);
        $(this).closest('.faq').removeClass('open');

        }else{
            var newHeight =$(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq_answer').height() +'px';
            $(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq_answer_container').animate({'height':newHeight},500);
            $(this).closest('.faq').addClass('open');
        }

});
```

});